# OR not working in C# if statement

Tags: c#

I am uploading files to a database and the method checks to make sure the correct file type is uploaded. If i check for each MIME type individually, it works fine, but when placed inside an OR it triggers the error.

```
if (formFile.ContentType != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
{
    modelState.AddModelError(formFile.Name,
                             $"The {fieldDisplayName}file ({fileName}) is not a valid file type.");
}
```

The above works fine, but when i add multiple filetypes(see below), it does not work

```
if (formFile.ContentType != "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" || formFile.ContentType != "text/plain")
{
    modelState.AddModelError(formFile.Name,
                             $"The {fieldDisplayName}file ({fileName}) is not a valid file type.");
}
```

I know this will be something simple, i am just not seeing it.

Comment: think about it: "if my car is not blue OR it is not red" - will always be true since it cannot be both (assuming it is only one color). Not to confuse with "if my car is not (blue OR red)"

Comment: I have two American coins that total 15 cents. One of them is not a nickel or one of them is not a dime. What are they?

Answer (score 6):

The OR is working correctly. The issue is that you want to use a logical AND (&&).

Comment: Thanks, i was basically trying to make my ContentType to equal all of the queried results(i see this now).

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you made a mistake.

Basic usage

```
if(True or True) {
    // TRUE
}
```

Your usage

```
if(!True or !True) {
    // False
}
```

Comment: "`(True or True) == False`" Well, XOR maybe.